# Occurred exception "invalid version format" on Netty project when I request http and https connection

Tags: java, ssl, https, netty

I'm using netty client now for making http connection, and I have a question when I add https connection in this project.
To add https connection, I've created another pipeline to add SslHandler and attached it to existing client code. Also created new handler for SSL handling and added it to the pipeline.
After then I've added handshake when a bootstrap connection was completed and it was succeed.
However I've got an exception as "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid version format: OK" when client handler is receiving response data from server.
I've succeed to get a response data for only one of https connection without any exception by simple test code, but when I rebuild it to my project and try to get some http and https connection then it failed.

Could you please let me know how I can fix it and what is the problem?